# How to modify a shared object with Caliburn.Micro for Windows Phone

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, caliburn.micro

I have an object which is used throughout the application and it can be modified by some ViewModels; how should I register the object in `AppBootstrapper`?

Consider the following code:

**AppBootstrapper**

```
protected override void Configure()
{
    this.container = new PhoneContainer(RootFrame);
    this.container.RegisterPhoneServices();

    var myObject = this.CreateDefaultObject();
    this.container.Instance(myObject);

    // ... etc.
}

private MyObject CreateDefaultObject()
{
    // blah blah blah

    return new MyObject {
        Status = "New"
    };
}
```

**ViewModel1**

```
public ViewModel1(MyObject myObject, INavigationService navigationService)
{
    this.myObject = myObject;
    this.navigationService = navigationService;
}

public string Status
{
    get { return this.myObject.Status; }
}
```

**ViewModel2**

```
public ViewModel2(MyObject myObject, INavigationService navigationService)
{
    this.myObject = myObject;
    this.navigationService = navigationService;
}

public ModifyIt()
{
    this.myObject = new MyObject {
        Status = "Modified"
    };

    this.navigationService.GoBack();
}
```

The scenario is:

1. The application runs and navigates to View1 which will display "New" on a `TextBlock`
2. The user navigates to View2 and executes the action `ModifyIt` (e.g. `Button` click)
3. The application navigates back to View1 and this time the displayed value should be "Modified"

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Actual Answer:**

In thinking about this, it will never work, the reason is you have your local variable which takes the container instance. you are not resting this instance in your second ViewModel you are actually overriding the local instance so that the container instance is not reference any more. So my final suggestion is to do as above and swap out a property value if you want to keep the code similar to your original implementation.

<strike>You are sort of on the correct path, the Instance will return the same "Instance" to you each time it is requested, because you set this as a new instance it will override your set each time it is requested.</strike>

Instead register as a Singleton.

```
container.Singleton<MyObject>();
```

This will let you modify the instance. The other option if you need to pre create the object is to move the construction of the object outside the `container.Instance` call like so.

```
 var myObject = new MyObject("new");
 container.Instance(myObject);
```

That will work for you

The difference between both by the way is that singleton is not instantiated until first request, instance is usually instantiated at the time of service declaration. We are currently finalising the Documentation for SimpleContainer and it will be available from next week.

EDIT:

So it turns out this doesn't work as you can see from the test below. The last assert will Fail. I will need to discuss this with the team as I don't know if this is by design or not.

```
    [Fact]
    public void GetInstance_returns_the_latest_updated_instance() {
        var instanceA = new object();
        var instanceB = new object();

        var container = new SimpleContainer();
        container.RegisterInstance(typeof(object), "A", instanceA);

        Assert.False(instanceA == instanceB);
        var returnedInstance = container.GetInstance(typeof (object), "A");
        Assert.True(instanceA == returnedInstance);

        returnedInstance = instanceB;
        var finalInstance = container.GetInstance(typeof (object), "A");
        Assert.True(returnedInstance == finalInstance);
    }
```

At this point my suggestion would be to push your assignment down one. What I mean is that your `MyObject` becomes an property of another object. That way you a free to swap out the property. Since the instance never changes it should work as intended. This is how I would do it which is why I made the original assumption. I tend to have a couple of application level services which wrap others so my constructor does not get stupidly long.

Comment: The second way you mentioned in your answer is actually what I'm doing, I haven't write it in my example because I didn't think it makes any difference... I modified the code :) anyway, still it doesn't wok for me. Also, the Singleton approach cannot be used as I want to initialize few properties not just calling the default constructor... any idea?

Comment: Let me run a quick test and get back to you

Comment: Sure... can you also modify your answer to match the type and object names of my question (and fix the incorrect `var myObj("new");`)? It makes it easies for people to compare and see what should be changed from the original code. Thanks

Comment: You're absolutely right; what was I thinking? :) I'm talking about your "EDIT 2", by the way... of course it won't work, I'm manipulating a different object the way I'm doing it; I just modified the property of the object and it worked. Now if I may ask, can we modify your answer to highlight the important part instead of making people read all the answer to find out the solution is simple? :) thanks